# Copy limited data from one collection to another in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to copy a collection of data for testing purpose, the original collection is too big for testing purpose, so I only want to get the first 50 records and copy to another collection in the same db.

I tried `db.test1.copyTo("test2").limit(50);`

Not only copyTo does not work, I think limit() does not work either. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the eval command. The deprecated db.collection.copyTo(), which wraps the eval command, can only be run against MongoDB 4.0 or earlier versions. For behavior and example, refer to the 4.0 or earlier version of the manual.

If you are running 4.2 or higher, use aggregation with `$limit` and `$out`

Comment: Thanks Joe for your answer. I found another way that works too.

`db.collection1.find().forEach( function(d)=>db.collection2.insert(d);})`